# How to display an error message through text in a record triggered flow

Tags: lightning-experience, visual-workflow, salesforce1-app, error-messages

Need to display an error message on a record triggered flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot raise any visual message from non screen flow.

You could definitely create a validation rule which, if triggered inside the flow, will be displayed for the user upon the action which triggered the flow.

A second option could be some custom component which would be subscribed to a custom event, which you could then probably publish from the record triggered flow.

Comment: Thank you  Damecek...

Comment: I have a scenario that a custom object A has team members, and I need to prevent users to add the same team member on to the single A record. can you please guide how I need to implement this ?

Comment: create another question pls